# Alternating feature list css

Tags: html, css

I know it's a simple problem but I couldn't put words on it in my researches, so here's a picture of what I want:
[image]

Basically, I have a list of features which I want to display that way, which could be seen as a vertical list where rows are overlapping. I tried using `:nth-of-type(2n)` css selector to alternate left and right alignments, which is currently working, and make the overlapping by setting vertical negative margins, but this makes all items move up, so there's no overlapping.

Also, since I want the design to be responsive, it should just display as a centered vertical list on mobile.

What's the better way to achieve that?

NB: Don't worry about what's inside the gray boxes, it doesn't serve the purpose of this question.

Code:

```css
.feature {
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.feature:nth-of-type(2n + 1) {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.feature:nth-of-type(2n) {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 0;
  /*margin-top: -60px*/
}
```

Comment: Could you please share some code to allow us testing and show what you have tried so far?

Comment: You can look into CSS Grid layout. An example of what you're looking for can be found [here](https://www.quackit.com/html/html_editors/scratchpad/?example=/css/grid/examples/12_column_grid_vertical_mobile_first)

Comment: give us some (that you have tried so far) code that we can work on.

Comment: @Helenesh hmm okay but how can I make the overlapping/offset effect?

Comment: @Partho63 I added the relevant code.

Comment: Please post the html aswell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use translation to translate the right boxes to the bottom or the left one to the top

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.feature {
  flex: 0 1 45%;
  margin: 5px 2%;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.feature:nth-of-type(2n) {
  transform: translateY(50px);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="feature"></div>
  <div class="feature"></div>
  <div class="feature"></div>
  <div class="feature"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is only good when he uses just 4 div, But once he adds more div then they design pattern won't look great, It will break.

Comment: @ThanveerShah this will work with any number of divs if he keep 2 columns and same height div (like his screenshot). But it's trivial that the code will not work if he completely change the design. Each situation is specific.

Comment: This is indeed what I was looking for, thanks! I'm not planning on adding anything more. Only thing though, how do I make the features in a vertical centered list on mobile? I guess there's something to do with flex-shrink?

Comment: @Coconuts can you explain more? didn't get you

Comment: @TemaniAfif on mobile, or when the screen width is small, I want the features to be displayed one after another vertically, one per row, horizontally centered, keeping their width. What is happening now is that when I make the screen width smaller, the features shrink and there's still two features per line.

Comment: @Coconuts here is an idea on how to do : https://jsfiddle.net/mk7b0n63/1

Answer (score 1):

I have made some changes to the code of @Temani Afif, I just made it a bit more like how you wanted, By adding some more styling.

Also I have added the mobile view for this

[image]

Just add this CSS,

```
.feature:nth-of-type(2n) {
      transform: translateY(100px);
    }
    .feature:nth-of-type(1n) {
      margin-bottom: 100px;
    }
```

For Mobile Responsiveness

```
@media(max-width:600px){
    .feature{
        flex:100%;
    }
    .feature:nth-of-type(2n) {
      transform: translateY(0);
    }
    .feature:nth-of-type(1n) {
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }
}
```

Credits : @Temani Afif

Comment: but this is not what he want ... he want overlap

Comment: Thanks for the Mobile Responsiveness part, this is what I was looking for!